# How to manage old CSS classes?

Tags: css, version-control

Scenario: I have created a class name it **pbox** with its own border and background and shadow etc. to wrap product image and title . I use the exact same styles for last news to display last news image and title. When I review the website I decide to edit the background color for last news (not for products). When the project is big, I may forget that **pbox** is used also for products. How do you manage this situation?

1- Produce new class name for every different series of objects? Do you create 20 similar classes when you have 20 different type of content with image and title?

2- produce a new class name when I am editing an existing class and leave the old one unchanged? (even it is not used elsewhere; How do you make sure if this class is used elsewhere?) So do you have a lot of unused classes in your project?

Comment: Please use the parent CSS class.

Comment: you should make the good desicion early to avoid such questions/issues. if you know the project then you will be able to define your classes in a good way

Answer (score 1):

Well you can handle the situation using its parent class like this

Here both product and news block has the same weighed block class `pbox`

By calling the parent of the news block `.news` you can edit the background of its child

```css
.pbox{
 width:50px; 
 height:50px; 
 background:green; 
 border-radius:7px;
 }

.news .pbox{
background:red; 
margin-left:15px;
}

div{float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="products">
  <div class="pbox">
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="news">
  <div class="pbox">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This solution have some limitations when the child class has special rules. For example if `pbox` has `width:20%` but news has `width:100%` by default. If you want to put 5 object side by side then you can not use `.pbox` inside the `.news`.

Comment: Can you tell me what is your expected output

Comment: I am sorry that this question is too general! I am about writing a big project and I noticed that I am confusing about managing classes. My question is not about a special output but looking for others how they manage thousands of classes where those are used?